# Embed a "node add" form in a page

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I'm looking for a way to embed a "node add" form on a landing page.
I was using [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock), but it appears to bring many error because I was using a development snapshot version.

Comment: If you are having specific issues with form block the best place to look may be the issue queue for that module.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('nodetype');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: If you get an error that `node_add()` is undefined, you'll want to add `if (!function_exists('node_add')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
}` at the beginning. This information comes from here: (http://kahthong.com/2012/01/embed-drupal-node-form-anywhere)

Comment: There a way to put this in a block? Or does this have to be included in the tpl.php file?

Comment: I cannot use the code for form with Ajax elements (for example: file upload). [Possible solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/241307/20459)

Comment: @Dimetry see [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99763/10176) for using Ajax elements in an embedded node form.

Answer (score 18):

Although Daniel Wehner's [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3414/10176) is absolutely correct and works, I wanted to add two common problems I faced with this approach and workarounds how I overcome those problems. First my code, then the explanations:

```php
global $user;

module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$node = (object) [
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
  'type' => 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE',
  'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
];
$form = drupal_get_form('YOUR_NODE_TYPE' . '_node_form', $node);

print drupal_render($form)
```

Why I did it this way, instead of Daniel's simple [`node_add`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7)?

Problem 1: [`node_add()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7) function changes the page title to **Create 'node type'**, this is hard coded in the function.

Workaround 1: Instead of using `node_add` function, I've copied the code and removed the `drupal_set_title`. The above code is the same code as the `node_add` function, except from this one line.

Problem 2: In the embedded form some ajax functions didn't work. For example if you have a field that can have unlimited values, so that you have an 'Add another item' button, or if you have an upload file field in your form, they don't work.

Workaround 2: In your custom module, implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) for ajax call paths, and include `node.pages.inc`.

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['file/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['file/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
  $items['system/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
}
```

Comment: Would Inline Entityform be an alternative? I've been playing around with the module but haven't been able to display a node add form on the front-end, only when you edit a node can you provide an entityreference field that displays a node add form.

Comment: Inline Entityform is for entity reference fields, which is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: If you don't want to use hook_menu_alter() for file uploads, etc, you can add the include in a form alter for the node form instead:

`function YOURMODULE_form_NODETYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
}`

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Does your answer apply to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238447/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-to-a-view)?

Comment: @Umair My answer is only about adding a node form to a page. It would neither submit the form via AJAX nor would it update the view. However, you can achieve those using [AJAX Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7.x).

Comment: Note that there should be a closing quote around YOUR_NODE_TYPE in the $form declaration.

Comment: @kosher Thanks for the note. I've added the closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the accepted answer's code...

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('nodetype');
print drupal_render($form);
```

...inside of a page callback function, then `print drupal_render..` this results in a completely un-themed (broken-looking) page.

So instead, I just `return`'ed the `$form`:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('program_registration');
return $form;
```