# Ajax fields do not work on custom page with `drupal_render`

Tags: views, ajax, debugging

From my module `test` I render the create node form on URL `admin/test` using the following:

```
function test_menu() {
  return array(
    'admin/test' => array(
      'title' => 'test',
      'access callback' => '_test_access',
      'page callback' => '_test_render',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
    )
  );
}

function _test_access() {
  return true;
}

function _test_render() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('my_content_type');
  return array(
    'whatever' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => drupal_render($form),
    )
  );
}
```

Form works well and can create a new node of type `my_content_type`. The problem is that some fields where ajax is involved give me the following error when pressing "Add Items":

> Error: Call to undefined function node_form_validate() in form_execute_handlers() (line 1520 of /webapp/includes/form.inc).

[image]

The details of those fields are:

- Field type: Entity Reference
- Widget: View
- View display type: Entity Reference View Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found at [Embed a "node add" form in a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/embed-a-node-add-form-in-a-page/99763#99763). You have to  implement hook_menu_alter() for ajax calls.